# Toggling between camera modes

Tags: android, mobile, adb

This problem is a copy of [question](https://stackoverflow.com).

I am trying to toggle between cameras of my android device but using the above said commands (also pasted below), the camera face doesn't toggle. I have changed the command to open the actual camera [STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA] (which we use to manually open) of the device instead of just an image capture instance.

Front Camera

`adb shell am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA --ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 1`

Back Camera

`adb shell am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA--ei android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING 0`

This is the response I get when my camera is already on and I try to change the face.

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA (has extras) }
```

**Problem: I want to change the camera face using ADB shell but all I get is a flash on the screen and nothing happens.**

I am not able to understand my mistake here. Kindly help me with this problem.